# Omitting the fields with no value

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to publish exam result from a Google sheet. The search button shows the marks obtained perfectly if roll no is provided at the box but I need to omit the fields with no value like Subject 3, 5 etc. with their textbox from the html page

[image]

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16IH3yKJjLwM9XA0c4_BN5MVQSKh8hV7gR6_kLLfe8to/edit?usp=sharing) is the sheet I'm using and the code I'm using ...

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
       .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
       .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

//Search for the id and return the array for that row
function search(id) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16IH3yKJjLwM9XA0c4_BN5MVQSKh8hV7gR6_kLLfe8to/edit#gid=0");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var values = sheet
  .getDataRange()
  .getValues()
  .filter(function(row) {
    return row[0] == id;
  });

   return values[0];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
    .hidden {
     display:none;
     }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="text" id="txtName"/>
  <button id="show">SHOW</button>
  <h1>FMATS</h1>
    Name <input type="text" id="name"/><br>
    Roll <input type="text" id="roll"/><br>
    Subject 1 <input type="text" id="sub1"/><br>
    Subject 2 <input type="text" id="sub2"/><br>
    Subject 3 <input type="text" id="sub3"/><br>
    Subject 4 <input type="text" id="sub4"/><br>
    Subject 5 <input type="text" id="sub5"/><br>
  </body>
<script>
//When click on show button it will run search function
window.onload = function(e){ 
  document.getElementById('show')
    .addEventListener('click', search);
}

//Get the value for txtName input and run search function in code.gs
function search() {
  var txtName = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fillInfo).withFailureHandler(function (e) { console.log(e) }).search(txtName);
}

//It will run when a success response comes from search function in code.gs and updates the input with the sheet info
function fillInfo(values) {
  document.getElementById('name').value = values[1];
  document.getElementById('roll').value = values[0];
  for (var i=0;i<values.length-2;i++) {
    if (values[i+2]==null) {
      toggleElement("sub"+i);
    } else {
      document.getElementById("sub"+i).value = values[i+2];
    }
  }  
  //rest of the code here
  document.getElementById('name').value = values[1];
  document.getElementById('roll').value = values[0];
  document.getElementById('sub1').value = values[2];
  document.getElementById('sub2').value = values[3];
  document.getElementById('sub3').value = values[4];
  document.getElementById('sub4').value = values[5];
  document.getElementById('sub5').value = values[6];
}
</script>
</html>
```

I need to omit the Subject name and the text box with no value from the HTML page. And "Nothing Found" should be shown if a roll searched which is not in the table. It's not required but will be good if the Subject names come from sheet's row 1.

What should I do?

Comment: I would just build the html on the server side after getting the search request from `google.script.run` and then return the html to the `withSuccessHandler(function(html){document.getElementById("divid").innerHTML=html})`

Comment: I don't know JS well. Couldn't understand this :(

Comment: If you ever wish to under Google Apps Script you will have to study JavaScript 1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this:

1. Create your HTML on the server side (as [@Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper) said)
2. Manipulate your HTML with JavaScript

To create your HTML on the server side you can use string and "write" the html automatically.

Then your functions will be something like this:

```
//It will run when a success response comes from search function in code.gs and updates the input with the sheet info
function fillInfo(response) {
  document.getElementById("divid").innerHTML=html
});
```

If you absolutely want to manipulate the HTML on the client-side, you will use something like this:

```
function toggleElement(id) {
  var td = document.getElementById(id).parentElement;
  var tr = td.parentElement;
  tr.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

the usage is like so:

```
function fillInfo(values) {
  document.getElementById('name').value = values[1];
  document.getElementById('roll').value = values[0];
  for (var i=0;i<values.length-2;i++) {
    if (values[i+2]==null) {
      toggleElement("sub"+i);
    } else {
      document.getElementById("sub"+i).value = values[i+2];
    }
  }  
  //rest of the code here
}
```

and then you will have some css that does this:

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

## Edit:

This is how you implement the first solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="text" id="txtName"/>
  <button id="show">SHOW</button>
  <h1>FMATS</h1>
  <div id="dataDiv"></div>
  </body>
<script>
//When click on show button it will run search function
window.onload = function(e){ 
  document.getElementById('show')
    .addEventListener('click', search);
}

//Get the value for txtName input and run search function in code.gs
function search() {
  var txtName = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fillInfo).withFailureHandler(function (e) { console.log(e) }).search(txtName);
}

//It will run when a success response comes from search function in code.gs and updates the input with the sheet info
function fillInfo(values) {
  console.log(values);
  document.getElementById("dataDiv").innerHTML=values
}
</script>
</html>
```

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
       .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
       .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

//Search for the id and return the array for that row
function search(id) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("SHEETS URL");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var values = sheet
  .getDataRange()
  .getValues()
  .filter(function(row) {
    return row[0] == id;
  })[0];
  var legends = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues()[0];
  return createHTML(legends, values);
}

function createHTML(legends, values) {
  Logger.log(legends);
  var htmlResult = "";
  for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i]!=null && values[i]!=="") {
      htmlResult += '<div class="field">' + (legends[i]+"").replace("Sub", "Subject ") + '<input type="text" id="sub1" value="'+values[i]+'"></div>';
    }
  }
  return htmlResult;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It seems a piece of elegant advice but I'm very bad at JS. I've understood nothing about your first approach. About the toggleElement function don't I need to use an if clause here? like if the values[~] = Null then sub~ & the SubjectName (Best if the whole <tr>) gets hidden?

Comment: Hello @ImtiazSiddique, yes. I have updated the answer to show you how to use the function I provided effectively in your case.

Comment: I've tried to add as you advice but now nothing but the name and roll is being shown now :( https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbybej8nniKQi60n6qw_6ax8JymeWo4Hd57BobrsZKRmXjR2now/exec

Comment: here is the script : https://script.google.com/d/1XD_QpM-BcaOZLwh98AXkRXh4wVdoGDa7avKLvN1err7YRRQXIRJ4_zNB/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ImtiazSiddique Please update your question with the latest version of your code.

Comment: Done that. Only roll and name is being shown now :(

Comment: @ImtiazSiddique I've added a full version that works. Remember to accept the answers that help you.

Comment: It works perfectly! You are an angel Dude ... Thanks A lot :D

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a simple example of a complete solution of your problem done mostly server side.**

I like do it this way because I like to be able to use Utilities.formatString().

Server Functions: 
File: aq3.gs:

```
function search(sObj) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var hA=vA[0];
  var dObj={dA:[]};
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][0]==sObj.roll) {
      var row=vA[i];
      for(var j=0;j<hA.length;j++) {
        dObj[hA[j]]=row[j];
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  var html="<style>input{margin:2px 5px 0 2px}</style>";
  for(var i=0;i<row.length;i++) {
    if(dObj[hA[i]]) {
      html+=Utilities.formatString('<br /><input id="txt-%s" type="text" value="%s" /><label for="txt-%s">%s</label>',i,dObj[hA[i]],i,hA[i]);
    }
  }
  sObj['results']=html;
  return sObj;
}
```

Run the below function to get the dialog running.  The enter the roll you wish to see in the search box and click the search button.  You will get only the boxes that have data.

```
function launchExamResultsSearchDialog() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('aq5');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Exam Results");
}
```

The html:
File: aq5.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    function search() {
      var text=$('#srchtext').val();
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(sObj) {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=sObj.results;
      })
      .search({roll:text});
    }

    console.log("My Code");
  </script>
  </head>  
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="srchtext" /><input type="button" value="Search" onClick="search();" />
    <div id="results"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what the dialog looks like:

You can just keep changing the search roll number and the dialog will replace the data with the new data.  You can control the subjects by changing the headers.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Client To Server Communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

[Utilities.formatString()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatString(String,Object...))